# Converting from Hexadecimal to Bytes

Tags: java, hex

I have some Java code that converts a Hexadecimal string into bytes. It seems to work okay for very short hexadecimal strings but flags an error if I use a long string, but I cant figure out why. I'm new to Java and programming in general. Feel free to point out any other areas which I could improve.

Here is my code:

```
public class Hextobinary {

static String hexToBinary(String hex) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
return bin;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String h = "5F";
String x = hexToBinary(h);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

}

Many Thanks

Comment: "An error" -- which one? "A long string" -- how long? A terabyte, for example?

Comment: @fdama You should always include samples of actual data (failing and successing). Can you [edit] your question?

Comment: @gtgaxiola  Apologies. I c&p'd the wrong version. Corrected now.

Comment: @fdama I see... deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @Jongware The Strings that I am working with are around 1 - 3kb long. Apologies for not being specific.

Answer (score 3):

There is a built-in for this using [DatatypeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html), so you may not have to do it yourself.

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class HexUtils {

    public String toHex(final byte[] arr) {
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(arr);
    }

    public byte[] fromHex(final String str) {
        return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(str);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Todd, I've given this a try however only the first Hex is converted. How do I convert a whole string of hex?

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing your string to an `int`.  That will work for short hex strings, but not for longer ones.  An `int` is 32 bits, or 8 hex characters. Any string longer than that will not fit into an `int`.

If you do write your own method, then split the hex string up into two character chunks, and process each pair of characters separately into a byte, and store the bytes in a byte array.  That will allow you to deal with longer hex strings.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I'll give this a shot and challenge myself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using huge strings, the type int (Integer) of the variable i cannot store the value contained in the string hex. An Integer can only store values ranging from -80000000 (hexadecimal) to +7FFFFFFF. Any longer string will cause your function to produce false results.

One quick solution is to use the type Long (and the function parseLong) instead of Integer. The type Long can hold values ranging from -8000000000000000 (hexadecimal) to +7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. But if you need to convert longer strings, this is not going to work anymore.